# 3D print is not smooth, even with ironing turned on

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura, smoothing

I am *very* new to 3D printing and I cannot figure out what is the problem is.  I have checked all of the belts and (to the best of my knowledge) they are tensioned properly.  I also did the bed leveling, however it is manual and I did this by putting a paper between the nozzle and the print bed.

I think that my extruder is calibrated, in the sense that when a command is sent to extrude 50 mm of filament, it does.  I am unsure what else to check.

The attached image had 15 % infill in the cubic pattern and had ironing on for all layers, was sliced with Cura and printed on a Creality Ender 3 V2. Sorry about the huge size of the image.

The part that looks zebra-like should be smooth.

[image: Photo of not smooth print]

Comment: I haven't tried ironing it but I don't think it will always be perfectly smooth. By the way I suggest you look your settings and re-slicing. Or try printing a nicely sliced ironing enabled model. You can print a 10x10 mm calibration cubes to try it out.

Comment: Z heights are the problem. I had that problem 5 years ago,

Comment: @FernandoBaltazar How do I fix this?